# Default value for AngularJS ng-style

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I must be missing something with the syntax, but how can I have a default background color if the scope variable is unpopulated?

The following doesn't work for me:

```
ng-style="{('backgroundColor':button.color || '#FF6600')}"
```

However, this syntax works elsewhere:

```
<p>{{button.label || 'Some Text'}}<p>
```

What am I doing wrong with the ng-style syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the additional parenthesis and it will work:

```
ng-style="{'backgroundColor':button.color || '#FF6600'}"
```

Comment: Short and sweet. I knew it was something silly. Thanks!